# DeleteOnSubmit doesn't exist?

Tags: c#, linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;
```

That's my namespaces. I was looking for `System.Data.Linq`; but it doesn't seem to be anywhere, and I guess that is what have been moved to System.Linq, since I have access to most other things in Linq. I've found `System.Data:Linq`, but no difference.

Here is my method:

```
public void deleteStudienummer(int studienummer)
{
    dbcontent = new DBEntities();

    var dQry = from members in dbcontent.Medlemmer
               where members.Studienummer == studienummer
               select members;

    foreach (var member in dQry)
    {
        dbcontent.***
    }
    dbcontent.AcceptAllChanges();
    Console.WriteLine("delete member should have occured");
}
```

The `***` was supposed to be `DeleteOnSubmit`, but I only have `DeleteDatabase` and `DeleteObject`, I tried the latter but it doesn't work.

Have also tried `dbcontent.Medlemmer.*` but still not present.

And `AcceptAllChanges()` was supposed to be `.submitChanges()` but that wasn't present either.

Comment: I believe your namespace using statement only needs to be System.Linq. But you need to make sure you reference the System.Data.Linq assembly at the project level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know `DeleteOnSubmit` can only be called from a 'Table' not from a DataContext. Looks like you're trying to call `DeleteOnSubmit` from the context.

Should be `dbcontent.Medlemmer.DeleteOnSubmit(member);`

When using Linq to Entities as in this case `dbContent.DeleteObject(member)` can be used to mark for deletion. After that `dbContent.SaveChanges()` needs to be called to apply the changes. (`AcceptAllChanges()` won't do the deletion).

Comment: Not present there either. :-(

Comment: Are you using Linq to Entities ? So could `dbContent.DeleteObject(member);` do the trick?

Comment: Yeah Linq to Entities, sry if it wasnt clear. tried doing that, doesnt delete anything

Comment: I'm not really a Linq2Entities person - so I read the doc: I guess `AcceptAllChanges()` won't do the deletion. In my understanding dbContent.SaveChanges() should be the method to persist the changes.

Comment: yeah it just gives an error, but i just read that aswell :-)
Else thanks.
if u just edit it up there ill submit it as answer

Answer (score 1):

You don't call `DeleteOnSubmit` on your `DataContext` - you call it on an `ITable` or a `Table<TEntity>`. For example:

```
dbcontent.Medlemmer.DeleteOnSubmit(member);
```

`DataContext.SubmitChanges` should be present though...

The namespaces haven't changed, so I'm not sure why `System.Data.Linq` isn't showing up for you. Do you have a reference to the `System.Data.Linq.dll`? I'm surprised your code is building at all if you don't have that reference, as that should be required for your `DBEntities` class.

Comment: Not present there either. :-(

Comment: @Anders: See my final paragraph - you need a reference to System.Data.Linq.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference to System.Data.Linq
[image: Picture]

Comment: @Anders: Is DBEntities in the same project, or a different one?

Comment: It is in under Properties - Datasources.. Is that good enough? :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
   foreach (var member in dQry)
    {
        dbcontent.Medlemmer.DeleteOnSubmit(member);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem as well and had to add the reference to `System.Data.Linq`.

However as well as adding the reference to `System.Data.Linq`, also remove the following `using` statments:

```
//using System.Linq;
//using System.Linq.Expressions;
```